# Combining PDFs with PHP from Encoded PDFs - Error: "Template does not exist!"

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

I am building a simple web service that needs to join two PDFs into one PDF file. I can pass both PDFs as text(base encode 64) with a POST to the service and the service needs to spit out the combined PDF as encoded text, The client will then re-encode and make the PDF.

I found this question here which got me started:
[Can TCPDF / FPDI accept PDF as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497408/can-tcpdf-fpdi-accept-pdf-as-string)

I found some sample code and the multiple libraries:

- [FPDI Example](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/)
- [TCPDI](https://github.com/pauln/tcpdi)<-setSourceData(string)
- [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

Here is an encoded PDF single page simple.(Post data)
http://pastebin.com/zLXmCNJt

Here's my code:

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/FPDF/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/FPDF/tcpdf/tcpdi.php');


class ConcatPdf extends TCPDI 
{
    public $files = array();

    public function setFiles($files)
    {
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    public function concat()
    {
        foreach($this->files AS $file) {
            //$pageCount = $this->setSourceFile($file);
            $pageCount = $this->setSourceData($file);//i modified this
            for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
                 $tplIdx = $this->ImportPage($pageNo);
                 $s = $this->getTemplatesize($tplIdx);
                 $this->AddPage($s['w'] > $s['h'] ? 'L' : 'P', array($s['w'], $s['h']));
                 $this->useTemplate($tplIdx); //error here
            }
        }
    }
}


$pdf641 = $_POST['pdf1'];
$pdf642 = $_POST['pdf2'];

$pdf = new ConcatPdf();
$pdf->setFiles(array(base64_decode($pdf641), base64_decode($pdf642) ));
$pdf->concat(); //!!error here!!
echo base64_encode($pdf->Output('concat.pdf', 'S'));

?>
```

Here is the error log from the server:
http://pastebin.com/q2vzZfft

What's going wrong here? How do I fix this?

Comment: `$pdf641 = _POST['pdf1'];` shouldn't that be `$pdf641 = $_POST['pdf1'];` ?

Comment: @Meroje thanks. Still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This issue has been resolved [via the Github issue tracker for TCPDI](https://github.com/pauln/tcpdi/issues/3#issuecomment-174543780); I'm answering here as well for the benefit of anyone who comes across this SO question.*

As per the [TCPDI installation instructions](https://github.com/pauln/tcpdi#installation), TCPDI is not currently compatible with the version of FPDF_TPL bundled with recent versions of FPDF.

Attempting to use the bundled version of FPDF_TPL can result in the "template does not exist" error; using the standalone version ([FPDF_TPL 1.2.3](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/#files)) should resolve this issue.  If you continue to get error messages when using FPDF_TPL 1.2.3, please log a Github issue against either TCPDI or TCPDI_PARSER (as appropriate), and provide a sample PDF which triggers your issue.